# d3.js: why is d3.geo.path() giving NaN?

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I am trying to do some online mapping with d3, but running into a problem when I try to plot a line between two points.

I have calculated the centroid of two polygons (source and target)

In the code:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(width)
    .translate([0, 0]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
```

From the JS console:

```
> path({type: "LineString",
      coordinates: [path.centroid(source_country), path.centroid(target_country)]});

"M277.05056877663407,121.67976219138909L-694.1792414247936,NaN"
```

Yet, the centroid calculations seem to be working fine (plotting those points shows them on the map)

```
> [path.centroid(source_country), path.centroid(target_country)]

[
Array[2]
0: 103.89396329123777
1: -41.453727169465765
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: -260.3172155342976
1: -245.57309459883245
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Any ideas why that NaN is appearing at the end of the path generated for my LineString?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're projecting the lat/lon coordinates twice. The `path()` operator expects to take lat/lon and project to pixels; the `path.centroid()` method also expects a lat/lon geometry, and also produces a pixel-based projection.

So when you call `path` on `[path.centroid(...), path.centroid(...)]`, you're trying to project already-projected coordinates. You get at `NaN` because the y-position of the pixel coordinates, -245, is out of bounds for a longitude value.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to use `d3.svg.line` to create the centroid-centroid path. I haven't tested this, but I think it would look like:

```
var line = d3.svg.line();
line([path.centroid(source_country), path.centroid(target_country)]);
```

Comment: that completely looks like the right right answer, but I haven't had a chance to try it out. As soon as I do, I will accept the answer. Thanks for the response @nrabinowitz!

Answer (score 0):

OK just now I met the same error,

for anyone who meet NAN problem:

1. the format of coordinate must be correct. e.g. for type `Polygon`, the coordinate must have a 3-level nested array. e.g. `[[[1,2],[2,3]]]`
2. coordinates must be float/integer, but not string (e.g. `1` correct, `"1"` error )
3. you can inspect the detailed content of the error result, e.g. `M...L...Z...` and find out where the error is.