# d3.js and python's googlemaps (more NaN from d3.geo.path())

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3.geo

I am trying to modify this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400) with data from cvs file with node and link data.  I have addresses that were obtained from python's [googlemaps module](http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/).  All the nodes have, two floats `39.338923 / -74.475714` that represent the longitudinal/ latitudinal (lng/lat) coordinates.  However, when I get to:

```
.attr("d", function(d) { return path({type: "LineString", coordinates: [d.source, d.target]}); });
```

in the said example, things get fishy.  Displaying the output of `path()` via `console.log`, I see `NaN` and `LNaN`.  I have looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468609/d3-js-why-is-d3-geo-path-giving-nan), and I am fairly certain all lng/lat values are "kosher".

Since I am very new to javascript, d3.json, and cartography, how should I go about trouble-shooting this problem?  I currently stuck.  Since `path()`'s output is a string, I could find the lng., lat. values that give the `NaN`.   Here are some examples:

```
`-77.3860976/38.9695545 ----->M757.197171551755,218.52497030237407LNaN,NaN`
`-77.3860976/38.9695545 ----->M757.197171551755,218.52497030237407LNaN,NaN`
```

There is a lot of link data that is not able to be used due to the problem.  I know there are lot of places the code could have gone wrong prior to this.  I will say that if I comment out the above `.attr("d",`..., there are no errors. Unfortunately, the links are not drawn in this case.  Any and all help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Have you check to see if your lat/long are the wrong way round.  The way you've stated 39.338923 / -74.475714 as longitudinal/ latitudinal coordinates seems the wrong way around to me.

Comment: Fairly certain, they are correct because the nodes are drawn correctly.  Also, when I switch the order, no nodes show up at all.  I will put the example I have on a server later today and share the link.